WSL2/Multipass install GNOME Firefox span hang at 1%
I'm installing GNOME on WSL2/Multipass, but the process seems to hang at 1% when it's installing the Firefox snap. It stays at this point for a long time without progressing. I just want to use Ubuntu to develop something about deep learning.
Selecting previously unselected package firefox.
Preparing to unpack .../0022-firefox_1%3a1snap1-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb ...
=> Installing the firefox snap
==> Checking connectivity with the snap store
==> Installing the firefox snap
2024-11-08T06:33:10Z INFO Waiting for automatic snapd restart...

Progress: [  1%] [#...........................................................

